# Como puedo filtrar los productos de un array? Vuejs

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

Estoy intentando filtrar los productos de un array para asi mostrarlos, si funciona el filtro pero como puedo hacer para que retorne un valor si no encuentra coincidencia? por ahora tengo mi filtro asi:

```
findproduct: function() {
        if (this.product === "") {
            this.listFinishedproducts = this.filterFinishedproducts;
        }else {
            this.listFinishedproducts = this.filterFinishedproducts.filter(products => {
                return products.room.match(this.product.toLowerCase()) 
                || products.name.match(this.product.toLowerCase())
                || products.lot.match(this.product.toLowerCase())
                || products.quantity_packed.match(this.product.toLowerCase())
                || products.pallet.match(this.product.toLowerCase());
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no encuentra coincidencia tendrás un array vacío, así que basta con que asignes el valor que quieras a this.listFinishedproducts

```
findproduct: function() {
        if (this.product === "") {
            this.listFinishedproducts = this.filterFinishedproducts;
        }else {
            this.listFinishedproducts = this.filterFinishedproducts.filter(products => {
                return products.room.match(this.product.toLowerCase()) 
                || products.name.match(this.product.toLowerCase())
                || products.lot.match(this.product.toLowerCase())
                || products.quantity_packed.match(this.product.toLowerCase())
                || products.pallet.match(this.product.toLowerCase());
            });
            if(!this.listFinishedproducts) this.listFinishedproducts = "No encontrado";
        }
    }
```

Comment: si, hace unos min se me paso por la mente, muchas gracias r4ziel, siempre respondiendome xDDDDD, love u <3

Comment: Así aprendemos todos. Saludos!